# No CPU/ABI system image found after installing system image

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I tried to create AVD but its showing No CPU/ABI system image found error
in fact I have installed all the packages.[image]
Thanks

Comment: download latest SDK.

Comment: redownload android eclipse and sdk

Comment: In your SDK manager, go up to Tools > Manage Add On Sites... and make sure everything is checked.